# i cant get json array value using loop for (PHP)

Tags: php, json

i have 1 json but i cant get a value using for loop

```
$string = [{"lt":"1","lot":["1","1","1","1","1"]},{"lt":"2","lot":["0","0","0","0","0"]},{"lt":"3","lot":["0","0","0","0","0","0"]}]
$json = json_decode($string,true);
for($i = 0;$i<count($json);$i++){
    for($j = 0;$j<count($json->lot);$i++){
        if($json->lot==0){
            echo $j;
        }
    }
}
```

i got this error : Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: $json is array, use `$json['lot']` instead of `$json->lot`

Answer (score 0):

edit your code :

```
$json = [{"lt":"1","lot":["1","1","1","1","1"]},{"lt":"2","lot":["0","0","0","0","0"]},{"lt":"3","lot":["0","0","0","0","0","0"]}]
$json = json_decode($json);
for($i = 0;$i<count($json);$i++){
    for($j = 0;$j<count($json->lot);$i++){
        if($json->lot==0){
            echo $j;
        }
    }
```

changes json to decode in array using php json_decode(). [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: im sorry im forgot add that to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You need to use json_decode on your json. Also, keep in mind that json have to be stored as string in PHP.

```
<?php
$json = ['{"lt":"1","lot":["1","1","1","1","1"]}','{"lt":"2","lot":["0","0","0","0","0"]}','{"lt":"3","lot":["0","0","0","0","0","0"]}'];

foreach($json as $data) {
    $current = json_decode($data);

    foreach($current->lot as $lot)
        echo $lot;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Used `json_decode()` function for decode `json` :

```
<?php
$json = '[{"lt":"1","lot":["1","1","1","1","1"]},{"lt":"2","lot":["0","0","0","0","0"]},{"lt":"3","lot":["0","0","0","0","0","0"]}]';
$json = json_decode($json);
foreach($json as $val){
    foreach($val->lot as $lot) {
        if($lot==0){
            echo $lot;
        }
    }
}
?>
```